# Gradle HttpFileServer, keep running, but kill on ctrl+c

Tags: gradle

During my Gradle build I need to run a simple web server to serve some static content. I’m using Gradle’s [integrated classes](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/index.html?org/gradle/plugins/javascript/envjs/http/simple/SimpleHttpFileServerFactory.html) for that.

Here's a very simple version of my `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'

task server() {
  doLast {
    def root = new File(project.buildDir, '/site')
    def port = 8765
    def factory = new SimpleHttpFileServerFactory();
    def server = factory.start(root, port)
    println "HTTP server started on $port"
  }
}
```

I'm facing the following two issues:

- When running `gradle server`, gradle executes, starts the server, and then quits (with the daemon obviously staying in the background and the server running, which leads to the second problem)
- I’ve no possibility to stop the server through gradle. When running `gradle server` again, I get an exception because the port is in use.

I’d fancy either of the following solutions:

1. When running `gradle server`, gradle keeps running until I hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, then the server is killed as well
2. There are two tasks, `gradle startServer` and `gradle stopServer` which are used to start and stop

How can I achieve this or is there a different, better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little hack-ish but it works, the server task will hang and the `SIGKILL` will kill the server too

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'

task server() {
  doLast {
    def root = new File(project.buildDir, '/site')
    def port = 8765
    def factory = new SimpleHttpFileServerFactory();
    def server = factory.start(root, port)
    println "HTTP server started on $port"
    while(true) Thread.sleep(1000)
  }
}
```

Comment: Simple and efficient, thank you! I found, that sometimes it takes a few seconds until the server is actually killed after hitting ctrl+c, but that's a non issue for my case.